# Dynamic Menu from ObservableCollection: Passing Item as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change a property in my main `ViewModel` based on the click from a menu, which is populated by a list of objects.

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Private field for products
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<Product> products;

    /// <summary>
    /// Private field for the product
    /// </summary>
    private Product product;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Product
    /// </summary>
    public Product Product
    {
        get => this.product;
        set
        {
            this.product = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Product");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a collection of Products
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get => this.plant;
        set
        {
            this.plant = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Products");
        }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeProduct => new DelegateCommand(p => this.SetProduct((Product)p), p => p is Product);

    private void SetProduct (Product product) => this.Product = product;
}
```

I'm trying to change the `Product` by clicking a `MenuItem` in a `Menu`.

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
    <MenuItem Header="Products">
        <MenuItem Name="ProductMenu" Header="Change Product" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Command="{Binding ChangeProduct}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ProductMenu}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

This, however, isn't working. How do I bind the `Product` attached to the clicked generated `MenuItem` as a parameter in my ViewModel?

Comment: This is because your passing the `MenuItem` as the parameter which is not of type `Product`

Comment: Yeah I figured that. How would I pass the `Product` that's attached to the generated `MenuItem`?

Answer (score 0):

Xaml could be something like this:

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
   <MenuItem Header="Products"   >
       <MenuItem Name="ProductMenu" Header="Products"  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                             <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding  ElementName=ProductMenu, Path=DataContext.ChangeProduct}"/>
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>

   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `CommandParameter` binding to just `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, i.e. remove the path:

```
<MenuItem Name="ProductMenu"
        Header="Change Product" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
        Command="{Binding ChangeProduct}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```